# Uniform distribution in probabilistic method

Tags: probability, statistics

On page 15 of https://yufeizhao.com/pm/probmethod_notes.pdf. Why is $\{n\theta\}$ uniform on $[0,1]$ if $\theta$ is uniform on $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed $n$, introduce the notation $Z$ to represent the random variable $\{n \theta \}$ where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part.

Then for any $a \in [0,1)$ we have $$Pr(Z \leq a) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} Pr\big(n\theta \in [k, k+a] \big) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}Pr\left(\theta \in \left[\frac{k}{n}, \, \frac{k+a}{n}\right] \right).$$

Now, using the fact that $\theta$ is uniformly distributed, we get that
$$Pr(Z\leq a) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{a}{n} = a.$$

This implies that $Z$ is uniformly distributed.